# JavaScript - difference between Date(), new Date(), and ISODate

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, utc

I've seen various versions of this question, but none of them answer my needs.

I want to create an ISODate for MongoDB and I'm using Node.js.

In Node, when I do:

```
console.log(Date());
```

I get:

> Mon Sep 26 2016 15:17:04 GMT-0400 (EDT) **<-- This is correct.**

When I do:

```
console.log(new Date());
```

I get:

> 2016-09-26T19:17:04.731Z  **<- This is 4 hours ahead**

My understanding of the way to do ISODATE is:

```
var isodate = new Date().toISOString()
console.log(isodate);
```

Which yields a time 4 hours ahead of "now".

My system date is correct.
I run this one different machines, and I get the same results.

Can someone please explain why I'm getting a discrepancy in time?

Comment: It's not 4 hours ahead. That `Z` at the end of the string means that it's a UTC time stamp. You're 4 hours behind UTC, but the two dates represent the same point in universal time.

Comment: this is probably your local timezone offset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `2016-09-26T19:17:04.731Z` related to GMT0 timezone and `Mon Sep 26 2016 15:17:04 GMT-0400 (EDT)` to your local timezone. Both are point to the same time :)

You can read more about data formats and timezones in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 3):

With a basic definition to the difference between `Date()` and `new Date()`
 is :

- Date() ignores any argument(s) passed to it and is equivalent of `new Date().toISOstring()`
- `new Date(Optional_arguments)` creates an `time` type object in JS on which you can perform :
- `getTime()`
  other `Date.prototype` functions listed on [MDN Website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- Date() is just a string representation of local time.

  - `new Date()` gives you a manipulatable object to fiddle around.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the `Z` at the end of `2016-09-26T19:17:04.731Z`?
It stands for Zulu, meaning UTC timezone (which is GMT+000).

As you can see in your original date string, `Mon Sep 26 2016 15:17:04 GMT-0400 (EDT)` has a `GMT-0400` timezone, which I guess is the local time where you live.
So, in fact there is no problem, just different representations of the same time:

- `Date()` creates a Local date
- `new Date()` creates a UTC date

Comment: Oops. `Date()` returns an implementation dependent **string** representing the current date and time. `new Date()` returns a Date **object** that represents the current date and time. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I know.  I feel like a dope. :-)  But I'm glad I asked the question.  Now I'm less dopey than before.  I appreciate everyone's responses!