# How can I convert "Thu Jan 02 2020 17:24:12 GMT-0000 (GMT)" into a Google App Scripts DateTime object to do more manipulation?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I grabbed data from an API which gave me timestamps in Unix epoch time format. I set the date I received from the API to 'epochtimedate'. I converted with

```
var date = Date(epochtimedate*1000);
```

When I wrote this to a Google Sheet with (second field):

```
currentSheet.appendRow([nickname,date,globalrating,xp,damage_dealt,damage_received,battles,all_time_average_xp,last_game_xp_avg]);
```

Google sheets converted that date object as a string e.g. `Thu Jan 02 2020 17:24:12 GMT-0000 (GMT)` - how do I convert back to DateTime object in Google Apps Script?

I'm going to modify original script to convert to a `dd-MM-yyyy` and `HH:mm:ss` for future API grabs, and which I will use in separate columns in a revised Sheet. I want to go back and convert the earlier strings so I can do Google sheet formula based on date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var date = new Date(epochtimedate*1000);
```

As RobG says in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710819/javascript-difference-between-date-new-date-and-isodate):

> `Date()` returns an implementation-dependent **string** representing
>   the current date and time. `new Date()` returns a Date **object** that
>   represents the current date and time

Comment: Thanks RobG, I'm comfortable changing the original behaviour so that it doesn't happen in future, I'm interested in fixing the date strings as I find them in the existing Google Sheet. I will read the date string from the sheet, do something clever to parse it back into a DateTime object, and write it back as I described in the OP.